# Initializing array returns null in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm doing a project using HTML5 WebSockets, with a PHP server using a websockets library right [here at Github.](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-Websockets)


My project also depends on knowing how many players are online.  The library has three abstract methods, `connected`, `closed`, and `process`.  In `connected` and `closed`, it takes a parameter `$user`, which is a custom class that has a random alphanumeric string as the variable `id`.

I have a `protected $users = [];` at the beginning of my class, inside my class, which extends the WebSocketServer that the library provides.  In my `connected` method, I `array_push` the `$user` provided to the `$users` array.  Then, in my `closed` method, I loop through the `$users` array, checking if the element in `$users` has the same `$id` as the `$user` provided, and then `array_splicing` that element away if that is try.


So.  Here's my problem.  When I run my PvPASCIIServer.php as root, and connect using a test web page, everything works fine.  BUT, when I disconnect, it says:

```
PHP Warning:  array_splice() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/PvPASCII/PvPASCIIServer.php on line 24
```

Shouldn't `array()` not initialize `$users` as null?  Why would it?  I've also tried using the literal format of initializing arrays, `[]`, but even that didn't work.  And even wierder, my `array_push` at the beginning of my `connected` function did not return an error message.  Logically, it should have worked and pushed a `$user` to the end of the `$users` array, so even if it was initialized null, it should have not been null after that.




My code, if you need it:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?
require_once("websockets.php");

class PvPASCIIServer extends WebSocketServer
{
    protected $users = [];

    protected function connected($user)
    {
        $this->send($user, "say Pong!");
        array_push($this->users, $user);
        echo $user->id;
        return true;
    }

    protected function closed($user)
    {
        echo "Client " + $user->id + " disconnected from the server.";
        for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($this->users); $i++)
        {
            if($this->users[$i]->id == $user->id)
            {
                array_splice($users, $i, 1); // <--  Line with the error
            }
        }
    }

    protected function process($user, $message)
    {
        // Yet to be determined.
    }
}

$host = "localhost";
$port = 3000;

$server = new PvPASCIIServer($host, $port);
$server->run();
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$users` needs to be `$this->users` just like everywhere else in your class:

```
if($this->users[$i]->id == $user->id)
{
     array_splice($this->users, $i, 1); // <--  Line with the error
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array_splice($users, $i, 1); // <--  Line with the error
```

Should be:

```
array_splice($this->users, $i, 1); // <--  Line with the error
```

Since you want to use the class variable $users and not the function variable $users

EDIT:
What John Conde also says (he was a little faster with typing ;-) )